# Missing number in binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

If I have order statistic binary balanced tree that has `n` different integers as its keys and I want to write function **`find(x)`** that returns the minimal integer  that is not in the tree, and is greater than `x`. in `O(log(n))` time.

For example, if the keys in the tree are `6,7,8,10,11,13,14` then `find(6)=9`, `find(8)=9`, `find(10)=12`, `find(13)=15`.

I think about finding the `max` in `O(log(n))` and the index of `x` (mark `i_x`) in `O(log(n))` then if `i_x=n-(m-x)` then I can simply return `max+1`.

By index I mean in `6,7,8,10,11,13,14` that index of 6 is 0 and index of 10 is 3 for example...

But I'm having trouble with the other cases...

Comment: Find x as you normally would. Then perform Depth first style search from x such that each integer is an increment of the previous. If it isnt then you found your integer.

Comment: @Striker But for `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9` with `find(1)` it would be `O(n)`, isn't it?

Comment: For worst case yes it will be O (n).

Comment: @Striker and I need `O(log(n))`... How can we use the fact it is an order statistic tree?

Comment: @Striker, your idea is correct, further leveraging BST property makes it possible in `O(h)` time, where h = height of the tree, which in worst case is anyways `O(n)`. So your comment was actually a clue to the answer. Find a tuned one below.

Answer (score 2):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), an order statistic tree supports those two operations in log(n) time:

- Select(i) — find the i'th smallest element stored in the tree in O(log(n))
- Rank(x) – find the rank of element x in the tree, i.e. its index in the sorted list of elements of the tree in O(log(n))

Start by getting the rank of x, and select the superior ranks of x until you find a place to insert your missing element. But this has worst-case n*log(n).

So instead, once you have the rank of x, you do a kind of binary search. The basic idea is whether there is a space between number x and y which are in the tree. There is a space if `rank(x) - rank(y) != x - y`.

General case is: when searching for the number in the interval [lo,hi] (lo and hi are ranks in the tree, mid is the middle rank), if there is a space between lo and mid then search inside [lo,mid], else search inside [mid, hi].
You will end up finding the number you seek.

However, this solution does not run in log(n) time, but in log^2(n). This is the best I can think of for a general solution.

EDIT:

Well, it's a tough question, I changed my mind several times. Here is what I came up with:

I assume that the left node holds inferior value and the right node holds superior value

Intuition of `find(x)`: Start at the root and go down the tree *almost* like in a standard binary tree. If the branch we want to go does not contain the solution of `find(x)` then cut it.

We'll go through the basic cases first:

- If the node I found is null, then I am done, and I return the value I was looking for.
- If the current value is less than the one I am looking for, I search for x in the right subtree
- If I found the node containing x, then I search for x+1 on the right subtree.

The case where x is in the left subtree is more tricky, because it may contain x, x+1, x+2, x+3, etc up to y-1 where y is the value stored in the current node. In this case, we want to search for y+1 in the right subtree.

However, if all the numbers from x to y are not in the left subtree (that is, there is a gap), then we will find a value in it, so we look into the left subtree for x.

Question is: How to find if the sequence from x to y is present in the subtree ?

The algorithm in python looks like this:

```
def find(node, x):
    if node == null:
        return x
    if node.data < x:
        return find(node.right, x)
    if node.data == x:
        return find(node.right, x+1)
    if is_full(...):
        return find(node.right, node.data+1)
    return find(node.left, x)
```

To get the smallest value strictly greater than x which is not in the tree, the first call is `find(root, x+1)`. If you want the smallest value greater than or equals to x that is not in the tree, the first call is `find(root, x)`.
The `is_full` method checks if the left subtree contains all number from x to node.data-1.

Now, using this as a starting point, I believe you can find a suitable solution by yourself, using the fact that the number of nodes contained in each subtree is stored at the subtree's root.

Comment: I think that we should use the fact that "the nodes of the tree need to store one additional value, which is the size of the subtree rooted at that node" and using this, create the function `find(x)`...

Comment: Good point, I forgot about this. Then the intuition is simple. Follow the path like in a classic BST. If you want to follow the left link, then check if there is a missing int by checking left's children values and the number of node they contains. If there is space, then follow the left link normally. If not, go right.

Comment: follow from root? or from `x`? if from `x` so I might even need  to go "up" the edges...

Comment: From root, while searching for x just like in a usual BST

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: Turned out my previous ideas did not work. I edited my post so you have a proper starting point, and went through the different cases.

Comment: @T.Claverie, please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar question.

There were no restrictions about finding greater than some `x`, simply find the missing element in the `BST`.

Below is my answer, it is perfectly possible to do so in `O(lg(n))` time, with the assumption that, tree is almost balanced. You might want to consider the proof that expected height of the randomly built `BST` is `lg(n)` given `n` elements. I use a simpler notation, `O(h)` where h = height of the tree, so two things are now separate.

**assumptions and/or requirements:**

1. I enhance the data structure. store the count of `(left_subtree + right_subtree + 1)` at each node.
2. Obviously, count of a single node is 1
3. This count is pre-computed and stored at each node

[image]

Kindly pardon my multiple notations for not equal to (`=/=` and `!=`)

Also note that code might be structured in little better way if one is to write a working code on a machine.

Moreover, I think, at this point in time, that this is correct. I tried as many corner cases as I could think of, and in general it works. Even if there is a counter example, I don;t think it will be that difficult to modify the code to fit that particular case; but please comment the counter example, I am interested.